# localization for struts2-Jquery

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, struts2-jquery

I want to make  localization for struts2-Jquery. I made localization

```
  <sj:head locale="ar" />
```

`"ar”` refers to Arabic language but it doesn’t work, grid paging give English number and date picker give English months and days and number.
What can I do to transfer to Arabic Language?
Note: I have the following installed:

- struts2-core-2.3.1.2.
- struts2-jquery-plugin-3.3.0
- struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

That's for specifying the default locale to be used by the jquery plugin.

For that to function, you need to have `ar` properties file configured in your struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global"/>
```

And then you must have a file named `global_ar.properties` in the classpath for it to work.